# Spring MVC: Path variable lost after first call to the controller method

Tags: spring-mvc

I have a controller method that is mapped to an URL that contains a path variable (`@RequestMapping(value="/{studentId}/activity/add", ...`). Since I'm doing some validation in this method, it may happen that the method gets called several times. The first call to the method works fine, but if I try to call it for the second time (for example, if I made some errors populating fields for the first time), the path variable gets lost and page `addNewActivity` cannot be loaded.

Controller method:

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/{studentId}/activity/add", method = RequestMethod.POST, params="saveNew")
    public String postAddNewActivity(@PathVariable Integer studentId,
            @Validated(Activity.ActivityAddNewChecks.class) @ModelAttribute("studentActivityDTO") StudentActivityDTO studentActivityDTO,
            BindingResult result,
            Model model) {

        logger.debug("Received request to add new activity to student");

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            model.addAttribute("studentActivityDTO", studentActivityDTO);
            model.addAttribute("courseList", courseService.getAll());
            model.addAttribute("teacherList", teacherService.getAll());
            return "addNewActivity";
        }
        else {
            Activity activity = studentActivityDTO.getActivity();
            activityService.add(studentId, activity);
            return "success/addActivitySuccess";
        }
    }
```

This is how the URL looks like the first time method is called:

```
http://someserver/essaysWebApp/essays/main/student/39/activity/add
```

This is how it looks like the second time method is called:

```
http://someserver/essaysWebApp/essays/main/student//activity/add
```

This is all I get in stack trace when calling the method for the second time:

```
[TRACE] [http-bio-8080-exec-4 12:54:10] (FrameworkServlet.java:initContextHolders:1018) Bound request context to thread: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@2bc04b7e
[DEBUG] [http-bio-8080-exec-4 12:54:10] (DispatcherServlet.java:doService:823) DispatcherServlet with name 'spring' processing POST request for [/essaysWebApp/essays/main/student//activity/add]
[TRACE] [http-bio-8080-exec-4 12:54:10] (DispatcherServlet.java:getHandler:1088) Testing handler map [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping@21a40993] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'
[DEBUG] [http-bio-8080-exec-4 12:54:10] (AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:getHandlerInternal:220) Looking up handler method for path /main/student//activity/add
[DEBUG] [http-bio-8080-exec-4 12:54:10] (AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:getHandlerInternal:230) Did not find handler method for [/main/student//activity/add]
[TRACE] [http-bio-8080-exec-4 12:54:10] (DispatcherServlet.java:getHandler:1088) Testing handler map [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping@62cc540b] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'
[TRACE] [http-bio-8080-exec-4 12:54:10] (AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.java:getHandlerInternal:127) No handler mapping found for [/main/student//activity/add]
[ WARN] [http-bio-8080-exec-4 12:54:10] (DispatcherServlet.java:noHandlerFound:1108) No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/essaysWebApp/essays/main/student//activity/add] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'
[TRACE] [http-bio-8080-exec-4 12:54:10] (FrameworkServlet.java:resetContextHolders:1028) Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@2bc04b7e
[DEBUG] [http-bio-8080-exec-4 12:54:10] (FrameworkServlet.java:processRequest:966) Successfully completed request
[TRACE] [http-bio-8080-exec-4 12:54:10] (AbstractApplicationContext.java:publishEvent:332) Publishing event in WebApplicationContext for namespace 'spring-servlet': ServletRequestHandledEvent: url=[/essaysWebApp/essays/main/student//activity/add]; client=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]; method=[POST]; servlet=[spring]; session=[null]; user=[null]; time=[16ms]; status=[OK]
[TRACE] [http-bio-8080-exec-4 12:54:10] (AbstractApplicationContext.java:publishEvent:332) Publishing event in Root WebApplicationContext: ServletRequestHandledEvent: url=[/essaysWebApp/essays/main/student//activity/add]; client=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]; method=[POST]; servlet=[spring]; session=[null]; user=[null]; time=[16ms]; status=[OK]
```

I can even begin to understand why this happens. Can anyone please help?

I forgot to say that if user enters correct values to all fields the first time, `else` part of the `if` statement gets executed and everything works fine.

**Update**: This is the jsp page the controller is mapped to:

```
<c:url var="studentUrl" value="/essays/main/student/${studentActivityDTO.student.studentId}/activity/add" />
<form:form modelAttribute="studentActivityDTO" method="POST" action="${studentUrl}">
<form:errors path="*" cssClass="errorblock" element="div" />

    <form:label path="student.firstName">First name:</form:label>
    <form:input path="student.firstName" readonly="true"/>

    <form:label path="student.lastName">Last name:</form:label>
    <form:input path="student.lastName" readonly="true"/>

    <form:label path="student.indexNumber">Index number:</form:label>
    <form:input path="student.indexNumber" readonly="true"/>

    <form:label path="student.program.programId">MK:</form:label>
    <form:input path="student.program.programId" readonly="true"/>

    <form:label path="student.rollNumber">Roll number:</form:label>
    <form:input path="student.rollNumber" readonly="true"/>

    <form:label path="student.rollYear">Roll year:</form:label>
    <form:input path="student.rollYear" readonly="true"/>

    <form:label path="student.program.programDescription">Program desc:</form:label>
    <form:input path="student.program.programDescription" readonly="true"/>

    <h2>Add new activity</h2>

    <form:radiobutton path="activity.essayFlag" value="Essay" />Essay
    <form:radiobutton path="activity.essayFlag" value="Other"/>Other

    <form:label path="activity.activityDescription">Desc:</form:label>
    <form:input path="activity.activityDescription"/>
    <form:errors path="activity.activityDescription" cssClass="error"/>

    <form:label path="activity.course">Course:</form:label>
    <form:select path="activity.course" id="courseSelect">
        <form:option value="" label="Select" />
        <form:options items="${courseList}" itemValue="courseId" itemLabel="courseDescription" />               
    </form:select>
    <form:errors path="activity.course" cssClass="error"/>

    Teachers:
    <select multiple="multiple" name="activity.teachers" >
        <c:forEach var="theTeacher" items="${teacherList}">
                <option value="${theTeacher.teacherId}">${theTeacher.title.titleDescription} ${theTeacher.firstName} ${theTeacher.lastName}</option>
        </c:forEach>
    </select>
    <form:errors path="activity.teachers" cssClass="error"/>

    <form:label path="activity.submissionDate">Date:</form:label>
    <form:input path="activity.submissionDate" class="datepicker"/>
    <form:errors path="activity.submissionDate" cssClass="error"/>

    <form:label path="activity.score">Score:</form:label>
    <form:input path="activity.score"/>
    <form:errors path="activity.score" cssClass="error"/>

    <form:label path="activity.note">Note:</form:label>
    <form:textarea path="activity.note"/>

    <input type="submit" value="Cancel" name="cancel"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="saveNew"/>
</form:form>
```

Comment: I removed the duplicates in your logs. You should really fix that. Check out `additivity` flag in log4j or logback, or whatever you are using.

Comment: This seems like a client issue. What kind of client are you using? How is your client constructing its urls?

Comment: Thank you for editing my post and for the tip @SotiriosDelimanolis, I will check my log4j. I've updated my post, hope it's all the info needed.

Comment: I would now ask you to post the form input elements. It seems like `studentActivityDTO.student.studentId` doesn't resolve to anything, ie. `null`, so EL replaces it with an empty String. In your handler method check that `studentActivityDTO.getStudent().getStudentId()` returns something.

Comment: I updated my post again @SotiriosDelimanolis. I will check if `studentActivityDTO.getStudent().getStudentId()` returns something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never submit the `student.studentId` from your `<form>`. As such, Spring cannot reconstruct your `StudentActivityDTO`'s `student` field with a corresponding `studentId` value.

When you add it to the model

```
model.addAttribute("studentActivityDTO", studentActivityDTO);
```

and forward to your view, there is no value for `studentId` which I'll assume is of type `String` or some `Number` class (ex. `Long`).

EL when resolving an expression `${}` to `null` will just print the empty `String`.

Just make sure to submit a `student.studentId` `<input>`.

Comment: Works! I added hidden `<input>` for `student.studentId` and voila! Thank you @SotiriosDelimanolis!

Comment: Dear @SotiriosDelimanolis, may I please bother you to look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21436955/spring-mvc-formselect-option-wont-stay-selected and tell me is it possible to keep selected option after page reload using <form:select> and not html <select>? Or should I just give up on that?

Comment: @just_a_girl Depends what you mean by reload. Consider looking into the POST-REDIRECT-GET pattern and flash attributes.