# Spring MVC: <form:select> option won't stay selected

Tags: spring-mvc, select

I have a simple form for adding a new teacher. I'm using Spring `<form:select>` in my view to show a list of teacher's titles, but when I select an option without entering teacher's first and/or last name, since I'm doing validation of all three fields, when the page loads after submit, previously selected option gets lost and "Select title" text appears again.

This is controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String postAddTeacher(@RequestParam(value = "title") Integer titleId, 
        @Validated(Teacher.TeacherChecks.class) @ModelAttribute("teacherAttribute") Teacher teacher,
        BindingResult result,
        Model model) {

    logger.debug("Received request to add new teacher");

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        if (titleId != null) {
            model.addAttribute("titleList", titleService.getAll());
            Title title = titleService.get(titleId);
            teacher.setTitle(title);
            model.addAttribute("teacher", teacher);
            return "addTeacher";
        }
        else {
            model.addAttribute("titleList", titleService.getAll());
            return "addTeacher";
        }
    }
    else {
        teacherService.add(titleId, teacher);
        return "success/addTeacherSuccess";
    }
}
```

This is view:

```
<c:url var="saveUrl" value="/essays/main/teacher/add" />
<form:form modelAttribute="teacherAttribute" method="POST" action="${saveUrl}">
<form:errors path="*" cssClass="errorblock" element="div" />

<form:label path="title"></form:label>
<form:select path="title" id="titleSelect">
    <form:option value="" label="Select title" />
    <form:options items="${titleList}" itemValue="titleId" itemLabel="titleDescription" />              
</form:select>
<form:errors path="title" cssClass="error"/>

<form:label path="firstName">First name:</form:label>
<form:input path="firstName"/>
<form:errors path="firstName" cssClass="error"/>

<form:label path="lastName">Last name:</form:label>
<form:input path="lastName"/>
<form:errors path="lastName" cssClass="error"/>

 <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form:form>
```

Just in case this is Teacher bean:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "TEACHER_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
private Integer teacherId;

@NotNull(message = "Teacher's first name is null!", groups = TeacherChecks.class)
@NotBlank(message = "Please enter teacher's first name!", groups = TeacherChecks.class)
@Column(name = "FIRST_NAME", nullable = false, length = 50)
private String firstName;

@NotNull(message = "Teacher's last name is null!", groups = TeacherChecks.class)
@NotBlank(message = "Please enter teacher's last name!", groups = TeacherChecks.class)
@Column(name = "LAST_NAME", nullable = false, length = 50)
private String lastName;

@NotNull(message = "Please choose title!", groups = TeacherChecks.class)
@Valid
@ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "TITLE_FK", nullable = false)
private Title title;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "teachers")
private Set<Activity> activities;

public Teacher() {
}
// getters & setters
```

I would like to keep my selected option after page reloads. I though it will happen automatically, like when I enter a value into a text field, it stays there even after the page reloads. Can someone please help me with this? Is there a way to do that from the controller, or it has to be done in the view, and how?

**Update**:

I added `value="${teacherAttribute.title}"` to `<form:select>`, as @willOEM suggested, but it still doesn't work. Now it looks like this:

```
<form:select path="title" id="titleSelect" value="${teacherAttribute.title}">
    <form:option value="" label="Select title" />
    <form:options items="${titleList}" itemValue="titleId" itemLabel="titleDescription" />              
</form:select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your model includes an attribute `title` that refers to a `Title` class.  This is not the same `title` you are referring to in your form, which is actually a `titleId`.  Since the `titleId` is not part of the `modelAttribute`, it should be excluded from the `<form:xxx>` tags.  You are going to need to use a plain-old `<select>` tag to pass the selected `titleId` back to the controller for processing.  Unfortunately with a `<select>` tag, you can't just set the value attribute with JSTL, so you have to conditionally set the `seelcted` attribute of the option, based on the `titleId` value (if it is set).  If `titleList` is a simple list of `Title` objects, you can create your `<select>` tag this way:

```
<select id="titleInput" name="titleId">
    <option value=""></option>
    <c:forEach items="${titleList}" var="title">
        <c:when test="${title.titleId== titleId}">
            <option value="${title.titleId}" selected>${title.titleName}</option>
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
            <option value="${title.titleId}" >${title.titleName}</option>
        </c:otherwise>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

In your controller, the `@RequestParam` annotation will pull the `titleId` out of the submitted data.  Since it is not part of the `modelAttribute`, you need to make sure this gets added as a model attribute:

```
...
if (result.hasErrors()) {
    if (titleId != null) {
        model.addAttribute("titleId", titleId);  // <--This line added
        model.addAttribute("titleList", titleService.getAll());
        Title title = titleService.get(titleId);
        teacher.setTitle(title);
        model.addAttribute("teacher", teacher);
        return "addTeacher";
    }
    else {
        model.addAttribute("titleList", titleService.getAll());
        return "addTeacher";
    }
}
...
```

Hopefully we got it this time.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @willOEM. I added `value="${teacherAttribute.title}"` to my view but it still doesn't work :( Is there something I need to change in my controller?

Comment: @just_a_girl: Please see my updated answer, there are a couple items I did not notice on my first pass.

Comment: I can't remove `path` attribute since it's required, should I set it to `path=""` instead? @willOEM

Comment: Now I get error `Required Integer parameter 'title' is not present` :( @willOEM

Comment: My mistake.  Since the `titleId` is not part of the modelAttribute, I don't think it can be a part of the `<form:xxx>` tags.  You probably need to just use a standard `<select>` tag and use EL to populate the options.  I'll try recreating this and updating my answer.

Comment: Also, I thought that when the form is submitted, `itemValue="titleId"` is passed to the controller, that's why I have `@RequestParam(value = "title") Integer titleId` in controller - `value` attribute of the `@RequestParam` is set to `path` attribute of the `<form:select>`, but `titleId` is passed. Am I wrong? I'm a bit lost now... @willOEM I just saw your new comment, so - ok :)

Comment: So I can't achieve what I want by using `<form:select>` at all?

Comment: @just_a_girl: Okay, let's give this another shot.  Please see my updated answer.  I tested this (in a simpler app) and it worked for me.

Comment: Just one more question @willOEM: what if my `titleList` is NOT a hash of key-value pairs, but just plain list of Title objects - `List<Title>`? Forgive my question, I'm a beginner.

Comment: If this is the case, you can reference attributes of your `Title` objects in your JSTL loop with simple dot-notation.  Eg. ${title.titleName} or ${title.titleId}

Comment: Thank you so much for the effort @willOEM. Problem is if I don't use `<form:select>` I can't use `<form:errors path="title" cssClass="error"/>` either, and all the bean validation I did was for nothing :( I guess there is no simple solution for this... I will accept your answer...