# Spring mvc - select set selected option

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm looking for a while now to find why it is not working for me...
I have a form to modify my client. The form display correctly almost all the informations.
My client have a "referent" and I can choose it from a list. The list is correctly filled but the referent already saved in my client is not selected...

The Client Dto

```
public class AbstractClientDto implements Demarchable{

private AbstractEmployeDto referent;
.... // getter and setter
```

The Controller

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/modify")  
 public ModelAndView modify(@RequestParam("clientId") Long id) {  
     Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();  
     AbstractClientDto client = clientService.getClient(id);
     model.put("command", client);
     List<AbstractEmployeDto> employes = employeService.getAllEmployes();
     model.put("employes", employes);
     return new ModelAndView("/clients/modify", model);  
 }
```

The jsp

```
       <tr>  
       <td><form:label path="referent">Réréfente:</form:label></td>  
       <td>
        <form:select path="referent" items="${employes}"itemValue="id" itemLabel="nomPrenom" >
        </form:select>
       </td>  
   </tr>
```

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing the code to below in your jsp

```
 <tr>  
       <td><form:label path="referent">Réréfente:</form:label></td>  
       <td>
        <form:select path="referent.id" items="${employes} "itemValue="id" itemLabel="nomPrenom" >
        </form:select>
       </td>  
   </tr>
```

Or you can try plain select tag also, refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21436955/spring-mvc-formselect-option-wont-stay-selected)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. You find the problem but I had to modify the path of the select and not the one of the label ;-)

        `<form:select path="referent.id" items="${employes} "itemValue="id" itemLabel="nomPrenom" >
        </form:select>`

Comment: @bryce yes correct, i have edited teh answer. +1 for review. :)